# How to avoid firing already destroyed boost::asio::deadline_timer

Tags: c++, boost, timer, asio

I'm using multiple `boost::asio::deadline_timer` on one io_service object. `std::shared_ptr` of `boost::asio::deadline_timer` are stored in the container `std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<debug_tim>> timers` with index.

In the timer handler, I erase other `boost::asio::deadline_timer`. However, it seems that the erased timer woule be often fired with success error code.

Is there any way to avoid that. I expect that the timer handler that corresponding to the erased `boost::asio::deadline_timer` always fires with `Operation canceled`.

Am I missing something?

Here is the code that reproduces the behavior

https://wandbox.org/permlink/G0qzYcqauxdqw4i7

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

// deadline_timer with index ctor/dtor print
struct debug_tim : boost::asio::deadline_timer {
    debug_tim(boost::asio::io_service& ios, int i) : boost::asio::deadline_timer(ios), i(i) {
        std::cout << "debug_tim() " << i << std::endl;
    }
    ~debug_tim() {
        std::cout << "~debug_tim() " << i << std::endl;
    }
    int i;
};

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<debug_tim>> timers;
    {
        for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i) {
            auto tim = std::make_shared<debug_tim>(ios, i);
            std::cout << "set timer " << i << std::endl;
            tim->expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
            timers.emplace(i, tim);
            tim->async_wait([&timers, i](auto ec){
                    std::cout << "timer fired " << i << " : " <<  ec.message() << std::endl;
                    auto it = timers.find(i);
                    if (it == timers.end()) {
                        std::cout << "  already destructed." << std::endl;
                    }
                    else {
                        int other_idx = i + 1; // erase other timer (e.g. i + 1)
                        timers.erase(other_idx);
                        std::cout << "  erased " << other_idx << std::endl;
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }
    ios.run();
}
```

I also call `boost::asio::deadline_timer::cancel()` before I erase the timer. However, I got similar result. Here is the cancel version:

https://wandbox.org/permlink/uM0yMFufkyn9ipdG

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

// deadline_timer with index ctor/dtor print
struct debug_tim : boost::asio::deadline_timer {
    debug_tim(boost::asio::io_service& ios, int i) : boost::asio::deadline_timer(ios), i(i) {
        std::cout << "debug_tim() " << i << std::endl;
    }
    ~debug_tim() {
        std::cout << "~debug_tim() " << i << std::endl;
    }
    int i;
};

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<debug_tim>> timers;
    {
        for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i) {
            auto tim = std::make_shared<debug_tim>(ios, i);
            std::cout << "set timer " << i << std::endl;
            tim->expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
            timers.emplace(i, tim);
            tim->async_wait([&timers, i](auto ec){
                    std::cout << "timer fired " << i << " : " <<  ec.message() << std::endl;
                    auto it = timers.find(i);
                    if (it == timers.end()) {
                        std::cout << "  already destructed." << std::endl;
                    }
                    else {
                        int other_idx = i + 1; // erase other timer (e.g. i + 1)
                        auto other_it = timers.find(other_idx);
                        if (other_it != timers.end()) {
                            other_it->second->cancel();
                            timers.erase(other_it);
                        }
                        std::cout << "  erased " << other_idx << std::endl;
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }
    ios.run();
}
```

**Edit**

Felix, thank you for the answer. I understand the `boost::asio::deadline::timer::cancel()` behavior. I always need to care the lifetime of `boost::asio::deadline::timer`. I my actual code of my project, the ``boost::asio::deadline::timer` is a member variable of another object such as a session object. And in the timer handler, it accesses the object. It's dangerous.

I consider how to write safe code. And I come up with using `std::weak_ptr` in order to check the object's lifetime.

Here is the updated code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

// deadline_timer with index ctor/dtor print
struct debug_tim : boost::asio::deadline_timer {
    debug_tim(boost::asio::io_service& ios, int i) : boost::asio::deadline_timer(ios), i(i) {
        std::cout << "debug_tim() " << i << std::endl;
    }
    ~debug_tim() {
        std::cout << "~debug_tim() " << i << std::endl;
    }
    int i;
};

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<debug_tim>> timers;
    {
        for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i) {
            auto tim = std::make_shared<debug_tim>(ios, i);
            std::cout << "set timer " << i << std::endl;
            tim->expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(1));
            timers.emplace(i, tim);

            // Capture tim as the weak_ptr wp
            tim->async_wait([&timers, i, wp = std::weak_ptr<debug_tim>(tim)](auto ec){
                    std::cout << "timer fired " << i << " : " <<  ec.message() << std::endl;

                    // Check the lifetime of wp
                    if (!wp.lock()) std::cout << "  timer freed." << std::endl; // return here on actual code

                    auto it = timers.find(i);
                    if (it == timers.end()) {
                        std::cout << "  already destructed." << std::endl;
                    }
                    else {
                        int other_idx = i + 1; // erase other timer (e.g. i + 1)
                        timers.erase(other_idx);
                        std::cout << "  erased " << other_idx << std::endl;
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }
    ios.run();
}
```

Is this a good way to avoid accessing the deleted object that has the `boost::asio::deadline_timer` ?

**Edit**

My weak_ptr solution works well.

See
[How to avoid firing already destroyed boost::asio::deadline_timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43045192/how-to-avoid-firing-already-destroyed-boostasiodeadline-timer#comment73210067_43045433)

Comment: It took me three days to figure out the behavior of timer. Did your solution satisfy `I expect that the timer handler that corresponding to the erased boost::asio::deadline_timer always fires with Operation canceled`, that's exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [reference of deadline_timer::cancel](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html#boost_asio.reference.basic_deadline_timer.cancel):

> If the timer has already expired when cancel() is called, then the handlers for asynchronous wait operations will:
>
> - have already been invoked; or
> - have been queued for invocation in the near future.
>
> These handlers can no longer be cancelled, and therefore are passed an error code that indicates the successful completion of the wait operation.

We can know that calling `cancel()` can not cancel the timer which has already been queued for firing.

And it seems that the dealine_timer doesn't override destructor. (There is no destructor in the member list of deadline_timer)

In your code snippet, all timers will fire at almost the same time. Concerning that asio will use some internal threads, it's quite probably that when one completion handler is called, the others are being queued.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand the behavior of dead_time_timer. The reason that I want to avoid or want to know cancelled status is that I access the object that has the deadline_timer in the timeout handler.
Now, my goal has been changed to how to avoid accessing the deleted resource in the timer handler. So I updated (added) my question. Could you check my approach?

Comment: @TakatoshiKondo Yes, this is good. Just watch out for race condition when firing them concurrently.