# Boost asio concurrent timer cancelation problem with strand

Tags: c++, boost, concurrency, boost-asio

I am writing a program with the following function:

1. A server starts up and run `trans2C`, `trans2C` will set a `candidate_timer_` and call itself every 300ms. Let's say after calling the first `trans2C` the server's `term` is 0, then the handler calls the second `trans2C` the `term` is 1, and so on.
2. During every `term`, the server will start `RV`, and `RV` will set a `retry_timer_` to repeatedly call itself every 10ms. When setting `retry_timer_`, `RV` will check the `retry_timer_`'s handler number, if it's not 0, throw an exception.
3. I used the `boost::asio::strand` and there is only one thread.
4. Every time the `trans2C` runs, it cancels `candidate_timer_` and `retry_timer_`.

Let's say in a timepoint in `term` 8, the `RV` set `retry_timer_` to call itself after 10ms. But after 5ms, the `candidate_timer_` expires and calls the `trans2C` to enter the `term` 9 and cancels both the timers. In the normal situations the `retry_timer_` will be canceled so every time `RV` is called, there is no handler on `retry_timer_` and the program will loop forever. However it is not.

What's wrong with my program?

Reproducible code:

```
#define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>


namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;
namespace attrs = boost::log::attributes;

using namespace boost::asio;
using namespace std;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;


std::tuple<string, int> another_server("127.0.0.1", 7777);

class instance {
public:
    instance(io_service &loop, const string &_ip, int _port) :
            server_(_ip, _port),
            ioContext(loop),
            candidate_timer_(loop),
            strand_(boost::asio::make_strand(loop)),
            retry_timer_(loop) {
    }

    void run() {
        trans2C();
        ioContext.run();
    }


private:
    void trans2C() {
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "trans to candidate";
        cancel_all_timers();
        int waiting_count = candidate_timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(300));
        if (waiting_count == 0) {
        } else {
            throw std::logic_error("trans2C只能是timer_candidate_expire自然到期触发，所以不可能有waiting_count不为0的情况，否则就是未考虑的情况");
        }
        candidate_timer_.async_wait(boost::asio::bind_executor(strand_, [this](const boost::system::error_code &error) {
            if (error == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) {
            } else {
                trans2C();
            }
        }));
        RV(another_server);
    }


    void RV(const tuple<string, int> &server) {
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << " send rpc_rv to server ";

        int waiting_counts = retry_timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(10));
        if (waiting_counts != 0) {
            std::ostringstream oss;
            oss << "rv retry timer is set and hooks is not zero, it should be ";
            string s = oss.str();
            throw logic_error(s);
        } else {
            retry_timer_.async_wait(boost::asio::bind_executor(strand_, [this, server](const boost::system::error_code &error) {
                BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "rv retry_timers expires";
                if (error == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) {
                    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "rv retry callback error: " << error.message();
                } else {
                    RV(server);
                }
            }));
        }
    }

private:
    void cancel_all_timers() {
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << " all timer canceled";
        candidate_timer_.cancel();
        int retry_handlers_canceled_number = retry_timer_.cancel();
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << retry_handlers_canceled_number << " retry_timer is canceled by cancell_all_timers";

    }

    io_context &ioContext;
    std::tuple<string, int> server_;
    deadline_timer candidate_timer_;
    deadline_timer retry_timer_;
    boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> strand_;
};

int main() {
    try {
        boost::asio::io_service io;
        int _port = 8888;
        instance raft_instance(io, "127.0.0.1", _port);
        raft_instance.run();
    } catch (std::exception &exception) {
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << " exception: " << exception.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

CmakeList:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(raft)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK")


set(BOOST_ROOT /Users/ynx/boost/build)
#include(FindProtobuf)
#find_package(protobuf REQUIRED)

#if (protobuf_VERBOSE)
#    message(STATUS "Using Protocol Buffers ${Protobuf_VERSION}")
#endif ()


find_package(Boost COMPONENTS log log_setup serialization REQUIED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})


add_executable(test_boost_timer_bug tests/boost_timer_bug.cpp
        )
target_link_libraries(test_boost_timer_bug
        ${Boost_LOG_LIBRARY}
        ${Boost_LOG_SETUP_LIBRARY}
        ${Boost_SERIALIZATION_LIBRARY}
        ${Boost_WSERIALIZATION_LIBRARY}
        ${Boost_FILE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}
        ${Boost_THREAD_LIBRARY}
        ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY})
```

Handler tracking log can show something strange (I can't paste it here for that will exceed StackOverflow's 30000 text limit. But it is easy to reproduce it, just run the code), the last cancelation before crash show that it cancels 0 handlers while the "normal" cancelations return 1.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [How to avoid firing already destroyed boost::asio::deadline_timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43045192/how-to-avoid-firing-already-destroyed-boostasiodeadline-timer) and boost timer reference. A timer expired can not be canceled. I think I need to re-designed my program to fit asio::timer's behavior.
And here is the solution: [Cancelling boost asio deadline timer safely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43168199/cancelling-boost-asio-deadline-timer-safely)